# 301 redirect to SSL causing Certificate Warning

Tags: php, redirect, ssl, https

I'm trying to get rid of a certificate warning. I have the following code that executes before anything else, and forces the user to the https version of the URL:

```
if((!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "") && ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1')){
$redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: $redirect");
exit();
```

}

This redirects to the correct URL, but it seems to leave an SSL warning in its wake:

[image]

In the console I get this:

*(The page at https://mysite.com/special-offer/ displayed insecure content from http://mysite.com/special-offer/.)*

[image]

However if I visit the url ($redirect) directly, no SSL warning is given. All resources are being served over https.

Comment: Have you tried to redirect using htaccess ?

Comment: I've tried various things with htacess yes, but i must confess to not being able to get them to work. Looks like I'll have to revisit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP or redirect. Your web page has references to http resources. When this page is loaded using HTTPS, you get a warning.

Solution: review your web page and change the URLs to either "//www.domainname.com" (i.e. no protocol specifier) or to proper HTTPS addresses if applicable (some servers have different paths for resources accessible via HTTP and via HTTPS).

Comment: I cannot see any references to http on my page, the only 'http' is in a footer link href.

Comment: @ChrisJAllen "references" here are not hrefs (I used wrong word) but img locations, javascript source tags, i.e. the content that is loaded. Pay special attention to scrips embedded into the page - some of them might cause this problem when they include files with http protocol (not HTTPS). I once saw this glitch with Facebook's button (they have long fixed it but the effect was nasty).

Comment: @eugene-mayevski-eldos-corp I beg to differ.  I think the key here in the OP's question is that the https version worked, so your theory about references to http resources can't be true.  Try a simple 301 forward in an apache config to a https url text file.  Chrome says only 2 networking calls happen, first a 301 return, and the second, a call to the https url. Calling the https url directly results in a correct certificate in green. Calling the http shows the OP's error above. I believe that Chrome is counting the 301 as part of the page, thus resulting in an insecure protocol transition.

Comment: However, additionally favicon.ico is not listed here.  It's possible that favicon.ico is being called along with the http request, and, if that's not cached, then the icon would be requested over http.  I have managed to reproduce this.  Once the icon is cached, it's not called, so the resulting forward succeeds without making a second http request.

Comment: @tudor favicon.ico is requested by the browsers themselves, not referenced in the document.

Answer (score 1):

The SSL connection is established before you send the 301 Redirect. Because the Browser can't trust the redirect they Show a warning.

Comment: If I go the htacces route, and add
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

The error still remains (after cache cleared etc).

Comment: @Aragon0 If I request http, then I should get http until I receive the 301 forward (or a reference to something else contained in the resuilting page).  How can an SSL connection possibly be established _before_ the 301?  Can you specify more detail here as to what leads you to this statement?

Comment: There are two possibilities: Firstly there is Strict Transport Security. Secondly when you visit a page on the website that was secured with HTTPS, the reqeuest to the next one is obviously also secured.